# Additional data isn't being saved to a rich join table, but primary keys are saved correctly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

The problem:

I have 2 tables in a database - Users and Projects. It's a HABTM relationship, but I'm using a has_many :through instead, because I want to add some additional information on the join - specifically the role that user plays in the project they have access to.

For example, user 1 may have access to project 1 as an Admin, and have access to project 2 as a Guest.

Now, I have a basic login system and I know the @current_user. So when that user creates a new project using the form, they are automatically granted access to it. This works - Rails is adding the user_id and project_id to the ProjectRegistrations table, which I can subsequently query and have returned a list of all of a user's projects, or vice versa. But, when the project is created I'm trying to assign a string to the 'role' column of the join table (and it simply isn't playing ball!)

Okay so here is the new project form. It's very simple - a single text field where the user inputs the project name. There are an additional 2 hidden fields, one for the current user ID and one for that user's role within the project. For now, I've just added the role as a string while I get the functionality working. As above, the user ID bit works fine, it's the role field that's not playing ball.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "project[user_ids][]", @current_user.id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "project[role]", "Admin" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Here is my projects_controller code:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

And the private method that handles the params (in the same file):

```
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, {:user_ids => []}, project_registrations_attributes: [:role])
    end
```

The rails console outputs this:

```
Started POST "/projects" for ::1 at 2015-11-19 16:12:59 +0000

Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "project"=>{"name"=>"Test", "user_ids"=>["15"], "role"=>"Admin"}, "commit"=>"Create System"}

*then it does some user stuff here*

and does the SQL INSERTS:

SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `projects` (`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test', '2015-11-19 16:12:59', '2015-11-19 16:12:59')
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `project_registrations` (`user_id`, `system_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (15, 94, '2015-11-19 16:12:59', '2015-11-19 16:12:59')
```

So what's puzzling me is that the parameter is making it into the request, but Rails isn't actually inserting it into the join table. However, it IS inserting the relevant user and project ID. The table just looks like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | project_id | summary | role | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 83 |      15 |        91  | NULL    | NULL | 2015-11-19 15:23:31 | 2015-11-19 15:23:31 |
| 84 |      15 |        92  | NULL    | NULL | 2015-11-19 16:12:06 | 2015-11-19 16:12:06 |
| 85 |      15 |        93  | NULL    | NULL | 2015-11-19 16:12:40 | 2015-11-19 16:12:40 |
| 86 |      15 |        94  | NULL    | NULL | 2015-11-19 16:12:59 | 2015-11-19 16:12:59 |
+----+---------+------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I've read almost every question on the site that mentions join tables but haven't got any closer to making it work.

Some of the things I've tried:

1. I've added 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' into the corresponding
   models.
2. I've played about with the formatting in the project_params method, but from what I've read the way I have it now is the correct way.
3. I had the form code responsible for this written this way: <%= hidden_field_tag "project_registration[role]", "Admin" %>. This did change what the console outputted, but it still didn't save the data to the table.

Some pointers would be much appreciated! I'm quite new to Rails so I'm sure it's something really small.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Suggested that I try changing the line of code in the form from:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "project[role]", "Admin" %>
```

to

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "project[project_registrations_attributes][role]", "Admin" %>
```

but, that now throws "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" error. Researching a fix now (comments/hints welcome in the meantime...)

**EDIT 2**

Added project model for reference:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_registrations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :project_registrations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :project_registrations

end
```

Comment: You're sending `project[role]` in the form, but I think you want to send `project[project_registrations_attributes][role]`

Comment: Also don't send current_user id in the form.  Instead, get the current_user in the controller and assign it in the create method.

Comment: Thanks dude, that threw an error I haven't seen before (because I'm a bit of a ruby nuby, probably real easy!) Research commencing and details updated into the question.

Comment: Could you add the project model?

Comment: Sure, added. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with the project params.  Try some variations.  Here is a write up on a similar problem: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/29/rails-tricky-error-no-implicit-conversion-from-symbol-to-integer/

Comment: Another tool that may help - I use the gem `better_errors` and it gives a nice browser based UI for seeing errors and querying on the state of the app when it crashes.